# Erro rpy2.robjects no ubuntu - LookupError: 'show' not found

Tags: r, python-3.x, ubuntu

Simplesmente não consigo testar funções no python com o R.
No meu jupyter notebook fiz:

!pip install rpy2

E quando tendo importar o robjects dá erro:

import rpy2.robjects as ro;